# Почему не освобождается оперативная память в php-fpm?

Tags: php, php-fpm

Привет. Использую PHP 7.1 и php-fpm. Проводил тяжёлые бенчмарки с огромными json-файлами и их декодированием в многомерные массивы. В начале бенчмарков была оперативная память была занята примерно на 340 мегабайт. После проведения бенчмарков - 1,26 гигабайт. Я закрыл вкладку с php-скриптом, удалил файл бенчмарка. А память так и осталась висеть. Это как и почему? Помог только `service php7.1-fpm restart`.

Comment: Бенчмарк-то точно до конца выполнился?

Comment: @andreymal там загрузка нескольких огромных json-файлов в переменные и их `json_decode()` в многомерный массив. Даже на экран ничего не выводится.

Comment: что за мода создавать и удалять вопросы после получения ответа?

Answer (score 2):

Модель обработки запроса данного языка программирования в пуле с PHP-FPM состоит в том, чтобы получить входные данные, обработать их и очистить всю занятую память выделенную на обработку запроса по завершению инструкций. Гарантировано, что при завершении запроса память процесса будет очищена, но пока процесс работает, память будет занята.

Закрытие браузера != завершению работы скрипта, скрипт вероятно продолжил работать далее и декодировать его в многомерный массив, поэтому при перезапуске сервиса вы принудительно убили работающий процесс занимающий память.

При соблюдении следующих рекомендаций, проблем с памятью не должно наблюдаться:

1. Тяжелая и долгая задача не должна выполняться через PHP-FPM. Клиент должен, как можно быстрее получить ответ и это желательно должно измеряться в мс.
2. При выполнении долгой задачи, она должна быть отправлена на выполнение в фоновый режим, а не выполняться через пул PHP-FPM. Клиент может периодический запрашивать статус ее выполнения или получить уведомление о ее завершении.
3. Клиентский запрос не должен расходовать много оперативной памяти, обычно устанавливают максимальный лимит 32-64 МБ оперативной памяти, но это очень специфичная настройка и зависит от приложения.